# jQuery outer function parameters not visible within each loop

Tags: jquery

I have a an issue where $.each does not seem to be able to access the variable requiredFields from the $.each block.  I have tried looking at various stack exchange answers but none of them seems to solve my problem or at least not in an obvious way.  I don't usually ask on StackExchange as it follows a very legalistic and precise terminology which I am very poor at getting a mastery of so sorry for asking my question in such a clumsy way.

The issue is primarily with the allNonEmpty function which is supposed to test all required input fields of a form and test to make sure they are not empty.  The required fields are passed in the array variable **requiredFields**.  I have tried assigning to the **req** variable to see if the variable is accessible within $.each. My methodology is to put a break point inside $.each and see if I can refer to each **req** or **requiredFields** but in the Javascript console both show as undefined yet the **res** field is accessible.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

```
function allNonEmpty(inputs, requiredFields) {
  var res = true;
  var req = requiredFields;
  $.each(inputs, function (k,elmt) {
    if ($(elmt).is("input") || $(elmt).is("textarea")) {
      if ($(elmt).prop('type') != 'hidden' && $(elmt).val() == '') {
        res = false;
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  return res;
}
function contactForm(form, requiredFields) {
  $(form).submit(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var inputs = $(form).find(":input");
    $(inputs).each(function(k,v) {
      console.log(`k = ${k} and v = ${v}`);
      console.log('value = ' + $(v).val());
      
    });
    if (allNonEmpty(inputs, requiredFields)) {
      console.log("All not empty");
      console.log( $(form).serialize() );
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
  

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var requiredFields = ['name', 'email', 'requirement'];
  contactForm($('form.contact-form'), requiredFields);
});
```

Comment: You never use the variable `requiredFields` or `req` in the loop.

Comment: BTW, since `inputs` is a jQuery collection you should write `inputs.each()` rather than `$.each(inputs)`

Comment: You can't access it from the console because the compiler doesn't put unreferenced variables into the closure's scope.

Comment: @Barmar you are right!!  Never expected that it would act like a compiler.  Was thinking of it as an interpreted language.  Thank you.